# How to handle two table views in single view controller by using xibs as cell

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to use the segment controller with 3 segments. If I click on first segment, I should get one tableview. When I click on second segment, I should get second tableview and for third segment I should get 3rd table view. Here I am using XIB's for tableview cell. I tried something but I am not getting any data in the table. The table is loading. But the cell is not loading. I am giving my code below. If any one helps me, would be very great. Thanks in advance.

```
 var arr1 = ["1","2","3","4"]
    var imagesarray = [UIImage(named: "11.png")!, UIImage(named: "22.png")!, UIImage(named: "33.png")!,UIImage(named: "11.png")!,UIImage(named: "22.png")!, UIImage(named: "33.png")!]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       view_track.isHidden = false
        view_watch.isHidden = true
         view_ebooks.isHidden = true
        table_track.register(UINib(nibName: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell")
         table_watch.register(UINib(nibName: "ProgramMWatchTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProgramMWatchTableViewCell")
        table_watch.register(UINib(nibName: "ProgramEbooksTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ProgramEbooksTableViewCell")
        table_ebooks.delegate = self
        table_ebooks.dataSource = self
        table_track.delegate = self
        table_track.dataSource = self
        table_watch.delegate = self
        table_watch.dataSource = self
   self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

    }

 @IBAction func Segment(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segment_program.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
    case 0:
        view_track.isHidden = false
        view_watch.isHidden = true
        view_ebooks.isHidden = true
        self.table_track.reloadData()
        break
    case 1:
        view_track.isHidden = true
         view_watch.isHidden = false
        view_ebooks.isHidden = true
          self.table_watch.reloadData()
      name_program.text = "Videos"
        break
    case 2:
        view_track.isHidden = true
        view_watch.isHidden = true
        view_ebooks.isHidden = false
          self.table_ebooks.reloadData()
        name_ebooks.text = "Ebooks"
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}
}
extension ProgramMListenViewController: UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == table_track{
            return self.arr1.count
        }else if tableView == table_watch{
            return self.imagesarray.count
        }else{
            return self.arr1.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == table_track{
            let cell = table_track.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell") as! ProgramMListenTableViewCell

        }else if tableView == table_watch{
             let cell = table_watch.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMWatchTableViewCell") as! ProgramMWatchTableViewCell
            cell.img_watch.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
        }else if tableView == table_ebooks{
            let cell = table_ebooks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramEbooksTableViewCell") as! ProgramEbooksTableViewCell
            cell.image_ebooks.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }


}
```

Comment: you have to call reloadData() in the segment action button.

Comment: You can see my updated code .I already tried that ,Even though I am getting an empty table, cells are not loading

Comment: You are creating cells, but still returning "return UITableViewCell()"

Comment: you should return cell instead of UITableViewCell(). You could add a return cell in each if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return your cell, instead of always returning UITableViewCell()

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == table_track{
        let cell = table_track.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell") as! ProgramMListenTableViewCell
        return cell
    }else if tableView == table_watch{
        let cell = table_watch.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMWatchTableViewCell") as! ProgramMWatchTableViewCell
        cell.img_watch.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }else if tableView == table_ebooks{
        let cell = table_ebooks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramEbooksTableViewCell") as! ProgramEbooksTableViewCell
        cell.image_ebooks.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you need to return the respective `UITableViewCell`, depending on the table in order for it to be shown. You should watch for errors in `dequeueReusableCell()`, thus I recommend the following implementation:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var returnCell = UITableViewCell()
        if tableView == table_track{

            guard let cell = table_track.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell") as? ProgramMListenTableViewCell else {
                print("Error getting cell as ProgramMListenTableViewCell")
                return returnCell
            }
            /*Customize your cell*/
            returnCell = cell

        }else if tableView == table_watch{

            guard let cell = table_watch.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell") as? ProgramMWatchTableViewCell else {
                print("Error getting cell as ProgramMWatchTableViewCell")
                return returnCell
            }
            /*Customize your cell*/
            cell.img_watch.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
            returnCell = cell

        }else if tableView == table_ebooks{

            guard let cell = table_ebooks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProgramMListenTableViewCell") as? ProgramEbooksTableViewCell else {
                print("Error getting cell as ProgramEbooksTableViewCell")
                return returnCell
            }
            cell.image_ebooks.image = imagesarray[indexPath.row]
            returnCell = cell
        }

        return returnCell
    }
```

This way you have a safe way of getting the correct type of your cell, editing it and returning it to the corresponding table.